# How do i call a mxml file in a pop up window

Tags: apache-flex

Sorry i am new with flex , i need some help.

I have created a mxml file , and i would like to display it in a pop up window.
i have alrdy done the pop up window, but i couldn't display the mxml file i have done .
I am **not** trying to call the pop up window in the mxml page.

this is my popup window i have done:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.controls.Text;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Button label="Cancel" click="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before your `<mx:Button>` open a new tag ('<') and start typing the file name of your MXML file.  Flash builder should auto complete it for you.  It should look something like this:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.controls.Text;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<yourComponentNamespace:YourCustomComponent />
<mx:Button label="Cancel" click="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);"/>
```

That's it. You can now set properties just like you would normally on all other components.

P.S.  If you're new to Flex and are just starting, why are you using Flex 3 instead of the newer Flex 4 components? (mx = Flex 3, s = Flex 4).